# Getting pids in an array in ksh script

Tags: arrays, shell, ksh

I am creating a script using ksh where a process (simple_script.sh) is executed and iterates 5 times. What I need to do is get the pid each time the process is executed and store them in an array. So far I can get the script to execute simple_script.sh 5 times,but have been unable to get the pid's into an array.

```
while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]
do
        ./simple_script.sh
        pids[$i]=$!
        i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: $! is used to get the PID of the last BACKGROUND process. Hence if you put a "&" after the call to your simple script, you will have all 5 PIDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andre Gelinas said, `$!` stores the pid of the last backgrounded process.

If you are okay with all of the commands executing in parallel, you can use this

```
#!/bin/ksh

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]
do
        { ls 1>/dev/null 2>&1; } &
        pids[$i]=$!
        i=$((i+1))
        # print the index and the pids collected so far
        echo $i
        echo "${pids[*]}"
done
```

And the result will look something like this:

```
1
5534
2
5534 5535
3
5534 5535 5536
4
5534 5535 5536 5537
5
5534 5535 5536 5537 5538
```

If you want to execute the commands serially, you can use `wait`.

```
#!/bin/ksh

i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 5 ]
do
        { ls 1>/dev/null 2>&1; } &
        pids[$i]=$!
        wait
        i=$((i+1))
        echo $i
        echo "${pids[*]}"
done
```

Comment: Did some minor tweaking, but this definitely pointed me in the direction I needed to go in. Thank you